# Как удалить из массива пустые значения

Tags: javascript

Есть массив в котором имеются пустые значения, например такой:

```
["70ef.jpg", null, null, null]
```

Как можно удалить из этого массива все значения равные `null`?

Чтобы в итоге из массива `['string', null]` сделать просто `['string']`

Answer (score 13):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
array.filter(element -> element != null)
```

Пример:

```js
const array = [1, null, "2", null, null, 3.0]
const array2 = array.filter(element => element !== null);
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = ["70ef.jpg", null, null, null]
console.log(array.filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: За что минус автору ответа?